# python - upload image into directory, save it and rename it

Tags: python, file, upload, save, rename

I want to upload an image "camera.jpg" and save it to "static/photo/" directory and then rename the "camera.jpg" file to "niloofar.jpg" file.

How can I do that?

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, render_template, make_response, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/me/my_flask_project/static/photo/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://myusername:mypassword@localhost/mydbname'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER





def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS



@app.route('/upload/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #return redirect(url_for('upload_file', filename=filename))
            os.rename(UPLOAD_FOLDER + filename, 'niloofar.jpg')
    return render_template('upload.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**upload.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Upload new File</title>
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <p><input type=file name=file>
     <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

I also tried this script below, but it does not even save the image into "photo" directory:

```
import os, sys


@app.route('/upload/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #return redirect(url_for('upload_file', filename=filename))
            os.rename(UPLOAD_FOLDER + filename, 'niloofar.jpg')
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving the complete target path in `os.rename`.

`os.rename(UPLOAD_FOLDER + filename, UPLOAD_FOLDER+'niloofar.jpg')`